# Chainlink wrong address

Tags: ether, erc-20, etherscan, chainlink

So I recently withdrew funds from binance to my wallet, unfortunately I input a digit wrong in the address and it’s gone elsewhere.
Is it possible to recover these funds or the funds are completely lost?

Sorry I have very little knowledge of the technical side of crypto but I have no idea where else to get advise on this.
Thank you
L

Answer (score 0):

If its not an existing address than the transaction should fail. If you sent your chainlink to a address that DOES exist the blockchain transaction is immutable. Your link are lost.

Comment: The transaction didn’t fail but the wallet it has been sent to has had no other interactions and the only balance is the link which it has received, so it’s lost there’s no way of creating any smart contract to ‘claim’ the sent funds back?